# The page jumps when using ui:inputDate for the first time

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, summer-16

I am trying to use  ui:inputDate  in our lightning component and noticed quite annoying behaviour of DatePicker. When you first time attempt to use field with ui:inputDate the page jumps. On second attempt, it works perfectly. 
I found the same problem with ui:inputDate when I tried to create New Task in Opportunity.
To reproduce it you need to put a scroll bar at top position on an Opportunity page.
[image]

After that choose Due Date and the page jumps.

[image]

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a known bug. You can track the status [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eYQkAAM) (Bug reference: 2993774)